# Requires peer of graphql, but it's installed

Tags: node.js, npm, graphql

I'm currently trying to generate a `prisma.graphql` file from my `.graphqlconfig.yml`, but I can't install globally `npm i -g graphql-binding` or `npm i -g prisma-binding` as I'm getting the following errors:

```
    npm WARN graphql-binding@2.2.6 requires a peer of graphql@^0.11.0     || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN graphql-import@0.5.3 requires a peer of graphql@^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN graphql-tools@3.1.0 requires a peer of graphql@^0.13.0 but none is installed. You must installpeer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN apollo-link@1.2.3 requires a peer of graphql@^0.11.3 || ^0.12.3 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 but noneis installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So I obviously installed graphql at a ^0.13 version with:

`npm i -g graphql@0.13`

This runs successfully, but the graphql bindings keep failing to install.
The command I need to run is:

```
  graphql codegen
```

But without installing the bindings I'm not able to run it.

Any suggestion on how to solve this is welcome :)

**EDIT** 
Using npx I managed to run 

`npx graphql codegen`

Comment: Could it be you just needed to type `npm i -g graphql@0.13.0` instead of `npm i -g graphql@0.13`? Let me know if that works and I'll throw up an answer.

Comment: No, that didn't help as with 0.13 I was installing 0.13.2 which is ^ than .0 so accepted by my requirements.
I'm still not sure about what caused the problem, but I started a new terminal session, used npx and it started working again.